# Is there a way to remove the lowest randomly generated variable in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Dungeons And Dragons character sheet in python, and I'm just working out the stat rolling currently but I'm not sure how to go about dropping the lowest of the variables.

I'm using Randint(1,6) under the variable name D6, so currently it looks like this
Stat = D6 + D6 + D6 + D6

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, instead of (or in addition to) explaining your code, always share the relevant part of your code, ideally enough for someone on here to be able to reproduce your issue and show how to adjust your code to get the desired result or solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a list, for example

```
from random import randint
stat = []
#assuming you're rolling the dice 4 times 
for r in range (0,4): 
    d6 = randint(1,6)
    stat.append(d6)

#this will remove the lowest one
stat.remove(min(stat))

#if you need the sum
output = sum(stat)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have something like this:

```
D6 = Randint(1, 6)
Stat = D6 + D6 + D6 + D6
```

This has a few issues (other than `Randint` definitely needing to be `randint`, and you should name your variables with lower case names as well, for reasons you'll run into as you learn more Python - Python is case-sensitive and capital letter names indicate classes).

Another problem is that `randint(1, 6)` is only called once, so your next statement just assigns 4x that roll's result to `stat`, but you really want separate results to be added up. And finally, you do nothing to drop the lowest result.

A better naive solution would be:

```
d6_1 = randint(1, 6)
d6_2 = randint(1, 6)
d6_3 = randint(1, 6)
d6_4 = randint(1, 6)

stat = d6_1 + d6_2 + d6_3 + d6_4
```

But you still want to drop the lowest roll. The easiest way to do that is to determine the minimum value using the builtin function `min()`, which works easiest if you have the values in a `list` or some other iterable.

For example:

```
four_d6 = [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]  # this list comprehension evaluates to a list

stat = sum(four_d6) - min(four_d6)
```

The `for _` just means we're not interested in the range value, we just want to get 4 separate evaluations of the first bit `randint(1, 6)`.

After this code, `stat` will be what you need, and `four_d6` will be the list of 4 rolls that led to the stat.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill for taking the 3 largest elements from a sequence of 4, but you can *express* this using the `heapq` module.

```
import heapq
from random import randint

rolls = [randint(1,6) for _ in range(4)]
heapq.heapify(rolls)
r1, r2, r3 = heapq.nlargest(rolls, 3)
```

Sorting is probably fine in this case.

```
r1, r2, r3 = sorted([randint(1,6) for _ in range(4)])[1:]
```